# Cassandra LWT - Read

Tags: cassandra

If I did a insert using LWT

```
INSERT .... IF NOT EXISTS
```

with SERIAL Consistency, when I am reading

```
SELECT * from ....
```

a row inserted by above transaction With QUORUM , would it succeed? Or I need to read back with SERIAL. If SERIAL CL is needed, Can you please explain the reason?

this doc suggests to read with SERIAL CL. 
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlLtwtTransactions.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you cannot write with SERIAL consistency. (LWTs have two consistency levels: serial-consistency and consistency. serial-consistency has two levels: serial (default) and local serial.)

Now suppose you wrote with QUORUM consistency and that write succeeded. Then, yes, reading with QUORUM would be guaranteed to succeed. Now, I am no expert, but as far as I understand, if you wrote with less than QUORUM consistency then a QUORUM read may not succeed, whereas a SERIAL read would.